# No puedo descargar ni subir repositorios mediante Git a Github

Tags: git, github

Resulta que me aparece el siguiente error al intentar subir mis archivos a mi repositorio en github.

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/JGuerreroS/Proyecto.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com

también sucede lo mismo al intentar clonar un repositorio desde github

Entiendo que debe ser algo acerca del proxy pero si alguien tiene algún enlace o guia que me ayude se lo agradecería

Comment: Puedes revisar [Could not resolve host: github.com](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4872)
o bien ejecutar el siguiente comando:  git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080

Answer (score 3):

Resulta que es algo sencillo de configurar, lo resolví mediante el siguiente comando:

```
git config --global http.proxy direccion de tu proxy:puerto
```

justo después de darle **enter** te pide el usuario y contraseña de tu **github**